# Tezos CLI keypair to software wallet

Tags: tezos-client, wallets, galleon

I have created an encrypted keypair using the tezos CLI using `tezos-signer gen keys alias`

I was not given any mnemonic words, only a password that I had to set.

I would like to use this address on a software wallet like Galleon, is it possible?
if so, do i need to retrieve the mnemonic from that address to be able to restore it? if so, should I use pytezos from baking-bad ? https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos

Has anybody already done that while being in the same situation as I am?

Many thanks!

Comment: Also, we noticed the following feature from both Galleon and Temple Wallet.
Does it mean that it doesnt support private keys from tezos-client? [![Temple Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzrlK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzrlK.jpg) [![Galleon Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwhMQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwhMQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can display your private key with: `tezos-client show address your_address_alias -S` and copy it for your new wallet

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to derive the mnemonic from a private key. Just create a new wallet using Galleon/Temple/Kukai/Atomex/other and transfer your funds using tezos-client.